# Adding a bulkhead to a framed/stud wall

Tags: drywall, framing, studs

I am looking to build a framed/stud wall that's roughly 3500mm wide and 100mm deep but I also need to add a bulkhead to a section of it, see the image below:

[image]

Do I:

**A:** Build the full width of the framed wall 100mm deep (adding extra
    studs for attaching the bulkhead) and then build/attach the bulkhead
    separately?

**B:** Incorporate the bulkhead into the framed wall design,
    building them as corners in the appropriate places?

The bulkheads run from floor to ceiling and serve no purpose other than aesthetic appearance and housing a few spotlights, they will have no load applied to them (other than tiles), will they need to be attached to the ceiling/floor too?

Comment: What are your finished dimensions, of the bulkhead?

Comment: The top section of the bulkhead is W2200mm x D300mm x H200mm and the verticals are W200mm x D300mm x H2400mm

Answer (score 1):

Normally I'd build the two separately, as in your first plan. However, I'd use pairs of studs in an L configuration as backing for the bulkhead. This provides interior drywall backing as well as a more convenient fastening scheme.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, where does the studs in an L configuration go?

Comment: At "Add stud?".

Comment: Ah ok, i've updated the graphic, is one of those solutions what you're talking about?